# WP-CLI update date and time format

Tags: wp-cli

I'm new to WP-CLI. After a lot of Googling and searching in this forum, I haven't found out which is the command to update both date and time formats.

wp option update......

Thanks for any help!

Regards

Comment: Last example in this list: https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/option/update/#examples

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The wp-cli command structure would be:

```
wp option update timezone_string "American/New_York"
```

So:

1. *option* to act on a WordPress option
2. *update* to update the option
3. the *option name*, in this case 'timezone_string'
4. the new *value*, in this case 'American/New_York'

Items 3 and 4 are defined by WordPress, a plugin, or other custom code.

Number 4, the value may have only a limited number of valid values. In this case, something other than a standard timezone would cause problems.

Generally speaking, I update the timezone, time format and start of week to Sunday.

```
wp option update timezone_string "America/New_York"
wp option update time_format "g:i A"
wp option update start_of_week 0
```

So research your basic [WordPress options](https://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference) to determine the option name and the valid values, then structure your command line appropriately.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot for all information!!